# When wrapping traditional asynchronous handlers to TPL Task<T> what happens to the Callback and State?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, azure, task-parallel-library, azure-storage

[This MSDN page has the following example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx):  The intent is to wrap an APM style task that can't be represented in the various `Func<T1, T2, T3>` overloads.

```
static Task<String> ReturnTaskFromAsyncResult()
{
    IAsyncResult ar = DoSomethingAsynchronously();     // <-- If this is an APM method, it's a bad example since most APM methods have a parameter for callback and state.
    Task<String> t = Task<string>.Factory.FromAsync(ar, _ =>
        {
            return (string)ar.AsyncState;
        });

    return t;
}
```

My question has to do with the function `DoSomethingAsynchronously();`.  Most APM functions I've seen require the parameter callback and state, which is missing in this sample.

**QUESTION:**  What happens to the callback and state parameters in "DoSomethingAsynchronously"

What do I need to do to properly call a function similar to this?  In my case I'm trying to wrap Azure Table calls like this

```
    Task CreateAsync(CloudTable tbl, CancellationToken token, object state)
    {
        ICancellableAsyncResult result = tbl.BeginCreate(null, state);  // Incorrect
        token.Register((o) => result.Cancel(), state);

        Task<bool> t = Task.Factory.FromAsync(result, _ =>
        {
            return (bool)result.AsyncState;
        });

        return t;
    }
    Task<bool> ExistsAsync(CloudTable tbl, CancellationToken token, object state)
    {
        ICancellableAsyncResult result = tbl.BeginExists(null, state);  // Incorrect
        token.Register((o) => result.Cancel(), state);

        Task<bool>  t = Task.Factory.FromAsync(result, _ =>
        {
            return (bool)result.AsyncState;
        });

        return t;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what the `state` parameter is for. It's there for *you*: when you pass an object in there, you can then retrieve it by accessing `AsyncState`. (And similarly `state` in `CancellationToken.Register()`.) In this case, you don't need `state` for anything, so you should pass `null` in there. That also means there is no reason for the methods you're creating to have `state` parameter.

The `callback` parameter is for code to be executed when the asynchronous action completes. The overloads of `FromAsync()` that you need don't use this, so you should also pass `null` in there.

It also seems you're confused about what to put in the `endMethod` delegate. As its name suggests, you should call the `EndXxx()` method in there (in your case, that's `EndCreate()` and `EndExists()`). If the whole operation returns something, it will be actually returned by the end method, so you should return that from the delegate. It will be then available as the result of the created `Task`. You can also perform some cleanup in the delegate. In your case, I think it makes sense to dispose of the cancellation registration there, since it won't be needed anymore.

So, your code should look something like:

```
Task CreateAsync(CloudTable tbl, CancellationToken token)
{
    ICancellableAsyncResult result = tbl.BeginCreate(null, null);
    var cancellationRegistration = token.Register(result.Cancel);

    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(result, ar =>
    {
        cancellationRegistration.Dispose();
        tbl.EndCreate(ar);
    });
}

Task<bool> ExistsAsync(CloudTable tbl, CancellationToken token)
{
    ICancellableAsyncResult result = tbl.BeginExists(null, null);
    var cancellationRegistration = token.Register(result.Cancel);

    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(result, ar =>
    {
        cancellationRegistration.Dispose();
        return tbl.EndExists(ar);
    });
}
```

For more information about this topic, have a look at [*Tasks and the APM Pattern*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/09/9716439.aspx) from Stephen Toub.

Comment: This is great!  I took your lead and wrapped every method and overload available in the TableClient.BeginXXX namespace.  [It's available here on github](https://github.com/makerofthings7/AzureStorageExtensions/blob/master/AzureStorageExtensions/CloudTableExtensions.cs).  Comments and critique are welcome, especially for the generic methods that use Segmented results.

Comment: The answer [given here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13428086/328397) greatly confuses me w.r.t. how to convert it into a Task<T> style function using FromAsync.  Can you give me some guidance on how this should be done?

Comment: ... in other words, are there any other FromAsync samples that illustrate how to use callbacks and state in TPL?

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly confuses you? Why do you want to use callbacks and state?

Comment: This is what my method looks like that I want to wrap into TPL (and eventually Dataflow)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13436514/328397

Comment: Here is a better view of the code I'm converting to TPL.  I just ported the results of the above answer into the code below:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13436670/328397