# How do I share an AsyncCallback with many APM BeginXXX calls?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, callback, asynccallback

I want to re-use my code with many APM-style async methods.  Each method has a BeginXXX and an EndXXX signature pair.  I want to reuse the same callback in each of the functions.

I have always used anonymous methods like the one below, but I'm not sure how to extract it into a reusable form.  I know this should be easy, but I can't figure out how to use a delegate to make this happen. (this is what I get for being self taught)

```
 var result = tableSymmetricKeys.BeginExecuteQuerySegmented(query, token, opt, ctx, (o) =>
                {
                    var response = (o.AsyncState as CloudTable).EndExecuteQuerySegmented(o);
                    token = response.ContinuationToken;
                    int recordsRetrieved = response.Results.Count;
                    totalEntitiesRetrieved += recordsRetrieved;
                    Console.WriteLine("Records retrieved in this attempt = " + recordsRetrieved + " | Total records retrieved = " + totalEntitiesRetrieved);
                    evt.Set();
                }, tableSymmetricKeys);
```

How do I extract the anonymous method with `(o) => ...` into a delegate and make it reusable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would create a class that has all of your "captured" variables as pass that along as state:

```
public class QueryState
{
   public CloudTable CloudTable{get;set;}
   public Token Token{get;set;}
   public class ManualResetEvent Evt{get;set;} //i'm guessing that's what this is
   //any other variables you were using
}
```

Then, you would create a delegate like this:

```
AsyncCallback asyncCallback = (asyncResult) =>
{
   QueryState state = asyncResult.State as QueryState;
   var response = state.CloudTable.EndExecuteQuerySegmented(asyncResult);
   //rest of method... make sure to use the state variable to get whatever you need.
}
```

Finally, you call it like this:

```
var state = new QueryState
{
   CloudTable = tableSymmetricKeys,
   //set everything else
}

var result = tableSymmetricKeys.BeginExecuteQuerySegmented(query, token, opt, ctx,asyncCallback, state);
```

Comment: I've been fighting this for 2 days; This is just what I needed! (x 1 million)

Comment: You're very welcome :) This crazyness though just proves why async/await in C# 5 is awesome.

Comment: I'm implementing this now, and `var response = state.CloudTable.EndExecuteQuerySegmented();` requires an IAsyncResult in the last method.  What should I put there?

Comment: Oops, sorry, my oversight. The "o" in the AsyncCallback delegate is the IAsyncResult. Let me edit and rename that variable and fix that mistake.

Comment: Just curious, could delegates have been an option?  Was I thinking in the right way, or will they not work / cause problems with this?

Comment: AsyncCallback **is** a delegate, that's exactly what we're using here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx