# Paging in Azure TableClient 2.0 using Segmented Execution

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, azure, azure-table-storage

How to implement paging in Azure TableClient 2.0 using segmented execution?
is it possible to implement the below function

```
    IEnumerable<Message> GetMessages(int currentPage, int pageSize)
{  

}
```

Based in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426430/how-do-i-use-azure-tableclient-2-0-beginexecutequerysegmented) i can Take the desired count of records, but i don't how to skip pages or set the starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available in the core platform. Windows Azure Table service offers a limited subset of query options defined by the ADO.NET Data Services Framework. For a list of options available, please see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135725.aspx.

In order to implement something like this, you would need to fetch the entire data on the client side (i.e. your application/service) and implement pagination. For smaller data it would be not that big of a deal but when you start dealing with large dataset, fetching entire  data would be an issue.